# Using pandas how to sperate column from one column specific row from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my csv file like

A      B    D
EB     AC   1
EF   2
MT   3

BM    AC    1
EF    2

I want like
A       MT
EB       3
BM       NULL

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(my_csv_path)
df = df[[my_list_of_column]]
```

it can be an easy way for your problem